# PySide2 Blur эффект для centralwidget, без наследования эффекта потомками

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qgraphicsblureffect

В классе главного окна накидываю эффект блюра на centralwidget, который имеет color: transparent; (основной виджет приложения, с кучей вложенных потомков). Делаю следующее

```
self.blur = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(self)
self.blur.setBlurRadius(50)
self.ui.centralwidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.blur)
```

Но эффект применяется ко всем элементам интерфейса = ко всем потомкам.

Есть ли варианты добавления блюр-эффекта фона приложения, без затрагивания элементов приложения? Может какая-то надстройка в stylesheets?

(Из того что я знаю, можно было бы взять белый цвет фона, и сделать его полупрозрачным, но это накидывает сразу белый фильтр на фон приложения, а надо чтобы цвета рабочего стола под приложением не менялись, только размывались)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй под centralwidget вставить другой Qwidget, а на него уже наложить BlurEffect

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.frame.setGeometry(0, 20, 500, 500)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(125, 125, 255, 150)")
        #   Чтобы self.frame был по зади self.centralwidget нужно его инициализировать раньше    
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.resize(500, 500)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")


        self.btn_close = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_close.setGeometry(200, 200, 100, 100)
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
        self.btn_close.setText("Click me!")


        blur = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()
        blur.setBlurRadius(50)

        self.frame.setGraphicsEffect(blur)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Example()
    ui.resize(500, 500)
    ui.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```